# Is it safe to uninstall qemu and libvirt?

Tags: fedora, uninstall, qemu

Fedora installs both by default. I didn't found what are them exactly for, but `yum autoremove` selects them for autoremoval.

Is it safe, for a normal user (I mostly use this machine for documents and programming) to uninstall them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qemu serves no system purpose-it is a cpu emulator for special purposes. Libvirt is a dependency of qemu. If autoremove selects them for removal, then you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The libvert and QEMU packages are apparently dependencies of GNOME Boxes, Fedora’s native hypervisor, so, if you uninstall them, you will also uninstall your system’s virtual machine.

Aside from that, based on my testing of Fedora 30 (including a system reboot), uninstalling these packages doesn’t cause any harm to the system.